# What is default mode for cookieless in web config in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

What is default mode for cookieless in web config in ASP.NET

Comment: Did you try google? There's plenty of hits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default is false. To enable cookieless sessions in your application, this is added to the web.config file:

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" />
```

Implementing cookieless sessions is just a case of setting this to true but refactoring your application to avoid storing valuable information in the session state is strongly recommended - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The default is `false`, you can find it on [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx)